# How to make the symbols used in a pdf output searchable?

Tags: macros, pdf, unicode

Is there is a way to enrich the generated pdf output from any tex source so that it contains the names of (some of) the symbols used? 
For example, let's us suppose that we have the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\def\mystigma{\symbol{"03DB}} % hex code of some symbol
\begin{document}
 Some pages...


 $\int_1^ x (t +1) dt=\frac{1}{2}(x^2+2x-3)$. This is the greek stigma: \mystigma. 

 More pages follows..
\end{document}
```

How we could redefine `\int` and `\mystigma` commands so that  one could be able to search the pdf for the words integral, stigma or mystigma?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `accsupp` package to provide the actual text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\def\mystigma{\symbol{"03DB}} % hex code of some symbol

\ifdefined\directlua % = if we are using LuaTeX
  \protected\def\pdfliteral{\pdfextension literal }
\fi
\usepackage{accsupp,etoolbox}
\newcommand\actualtext[2]{%
  \preto#1{\BeginAccSupp{ActualText=#2}}%
  \appto#1{\EndAccSupp{}}%
  \robustify#1
}

\actualtext\int{integral}
\actualtext\mystigma{stigma}

\begin{document}
 Some pages...


 $\int_1^ x (t +1) dt=\frac{1}{2}(x^2+2x-3)$. This is the greek stigma: \mystigma. 

 More pages follows..
\end{document}
```

The output doesn't change, but `pdftotext` now reports

```
Some
integral x pages… 1 2
1 (t + 1)dt = 2 (x + 2x − 3). This is the greek stigma: stigma.
More pages follows..

1
```

---

If you don't use ConTeXt you can ignore this part.

```
\definetypeface[main][rm][serif][libertine][default]
\definetypeface[main][ss][sans] [modern]   [default]
\definetypeface[main][tt][mono] [modern]   [none]
\definetypeface[main][mm][math] [modern]   [default]
\setupbodyfont[main]

\chardef\mystigma="03DB

\define[2]\actualtext{%
  \expandafter\let\csname saved_\string#1\endcsname=#1
  \define#1{\pdfactualtext{\csname saved_\string#1\endcsname\relax}{#2}}
}

\actualtext\int{integral}
\actualtext\mystigma{stigma}

\starttext
Some pages...

$\int_1^ x (t +1) dt=\frac{1}{2}(x^2+2x-3)$. This is the greek stigma: \mystigma.

More pages follows..
\stoptext
```

`pdftotext` reports

```
1

Some pages…
integral 1 ( + 1) = 12 (2 + 2 − 3). This is the greek stigma: stigma.
More pages follows..
```